# World of Warcraft Add-on XML error

Tags: xml, lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I am trying to learn how to start making a add-on for World of Warcraft. I am trying to follow the book "World of Warcraft Programming" 1st edition but seems things have changed. I am trying to setup the XML to just get something on the screen with no Lua yet. I can not find the error, any help would be awesome!

```
<Ui xmlns="http://www.blizzard.com/wow/ui/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.blizzard.com/wow/ui/
..\FrameXML\UI.xsd">

    <Script File="GD_Guild.lua"/>

    <Button name="GD_GuildFrame" parent="UIParent" enableMouse="true"
movable="true" frameStrata="LOW">
        <Size x="175 y="40"/>

        <Anchors>
            <Anchor point="TOP" relativePoint="BOTTOM" relativeTo="Minimap">
                <Offset x="-30" y="-30"/>
            </Anchor>
        </Anchors>

        <Backdrop bgFile="Interface\DialogFrame\UI-DialogBox-Background"
edgeFile="Interface\DialogFrame\UI-DialogBox-Border" title="true">
            <BackgroundInsets>
                <AbsInset left="11" right="12" top="12" bottom="11"/>
            </BackgroundInsets>

            <TileSize>
                <AbsValue val="32"/>
            </TileSize>

            <EdgeSize>
                <AbsValue val="32"/>
            </EdgeSize>
        </Backdrop>

        <Layers>
            <Layer level="OVERLAY">
                <FontString name=$parentText" inherits="GameFontNormalSmall"
justifyH="Center" setAllPoints="true" text="GD_Guild"/>             
            </Layer>
        </Layers>

        <Scripts>
            <OnLoad>
                GD_Guild_OnLoad(self)
            </OnLoad>

            <OnEvent>
                GD_Guild_OnEvent(self, event, ...)
            </OnEvent>

            <OnClick>
                GD_Guild_ReportDPS()
            </OnClick>

            <OnDragStart>
                self:StartMoving()
            </OnDragStart>

            <OnDragStop>
                self:StopMovingOrSizing()
            </OnDragStop>
        </Scripts>
    </Button>
 </Ui>
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working... do you get an error?

Comment: No error. But I do not get anything on the screen. The book says this should make a bock under my minimap but it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a log file or a way to turn on logging? This XML is not well-formed so there should be a syntax error, this might get ignored by WoW but would surely be logged.

Comment: Generally, WoW will not inform you of a syntax error. Best thing to do is to load up the XML file in Firefox, which will quickly tell you of such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a quote missing after name= in

```
<FontString name=$parentText"
```

However, this would likely cause an XML "syntax error" (malformed) so there may be additional problems. Perhaps your answer to the comments will shed further light.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I missed that quote and one here also
    <Size x="175 y="40"/>
And that seems to have fixed it. WoW is showing no errors.

Comment: What do you use as your editor? I saw that one mistake but just checked the XML plugin of notepad++ "validate" function and it picked up on both (first the parentText missing quote, then once that was fixed, the x missing quote). Different checkers will have different strengths and weaknesses.